# See recent outputs of a closed terminal

Tags: bash, terminal, linux-mint, terminator

I left my machine running some python and bash scripts last night on a terminal session, more preciselly using `terminator` bash on linux mint maya 13, and suddenly early this morning my computer unexpectedly shutdown (probably somebody stumbled on the power wire) before I come back to work.

Anyway, I had my outputs going to a log file, that's fine, but the outputs from `time` command were all displayed on terminal, which is closed now. Before I continue to use it, I'd like to know if there's something I could do to view some kind of history of terminator, those final outputs there, instead of re-run scripts (because it takes me 12 hours).

Comment: Check the properties of the terminal you are using. You may have a "logging" option that hopefully was activated.

Comment: nothing related to logging neither in terminal nor terminator :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid this kind of situations I usually use a terminal multiplexer such as `screen` or `tmux`.

Although they are ideal for working on remote machines (because you can disconnect and reconnect at a later time without loosing your session, say, in case someone trips on your powercord :) ), both have logging facilities of the sessions (which is what you want in your case).

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5832/is-there-an-equivalent-of-gnu-screens-log-command-in-tmux

Comment: Thank you! So, apparently I can't get my logs back this time, but if I use `screen` I might get lucky, should it happen again...